# What is the most succinct way of rewriting this function so it produces scroll bar position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouse, scrollbar, parallax

I would like to start using the [jParallax](http://webdev.stephband.info/parallax.html) jQuery plugin to accomplish a bi-directional parallax effect on my current project, however it seems the plugin was built to use the mouse movements as its method to scroll through elements.  I would like to disable the mouse position part of the plugin and use the scrollbars instead.

After looking through the code I found the function below which serves the plugin with mouse movements:

```
function positionMouse(mouseport,localmouse,virtualmouse){
  var difference={x:0,y:0,sum:0};
  if(!mouseport.ontarget){
    difference.x=virtualmouse.x- localmouse.x;
    difference.y=virtualmouse.y- localmouse.y;
    difference.sum=Math.sqrt(difference.x*difference.x+ difference.y*difference.y);
    virtualmouse.x=localmouse.x+ difference.x*mouseport.takeoverFactor;
    virtualmouse.y=localmouse.y+ difference.y*mouseport.takeoverFactor;
    if(difference.sum<mouseport.takeoverThresh&&difference.sum>mouseport.takeoverThresh*-1){
      mouseport.ontarget=true;
    }
  } else {
    virtualmouse.x=localmouse.x;virtualmouse.y=localmouse.y;
  }
}
```

How can I alter this code to return scrollbar movements?  After, I will figure out how to alter the plugin to enable an option so you can easily switch between mouse or scrollbar control.  Any direction or help would be greatly appreciated!

It would be great if this became a fork afterwards.